# Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular I upgraded angular cli after I always get this error and ng build doesnt work. Is that related TS error? How can I solve this problem?

Error is

> ```
> app/analyse/demography/age/age.component.ts:18:9 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. 
> 18 this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => {
> ```

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-age',
    templateUrl: './age.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./age.component.scss']
})
export class AgeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => {

        })           
    }

}
```

Another problem is I want to push object to an array

```
app/analyse/neighborhood/neighborhood.component.ts:169:74 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
                                           
this.barChartLabels.push(response.result[0].label[a].n);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put "object?.object?.method(...)" and it will stop the chain if an object is null, getting rid of the null warning.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Should be something like "this.route?.parent?.params?.subscribe(params => {"

Comment: thanks worked and the other response?.result[0]?.label[a]?.n didnt work is it right?

Comment: I saw online that that was due to a type error, Typescript can't tell the type and it doesn't like it, possibly your barChartLabels is missing ": someType[]" after